# R: Custom cuts using `choropleth` in `{GISTools}`

Tags: r, choropleth

I am plotting some data on a shapefile using R and `choropleth` in `{GISTools}`
I would like to modify my code below in order to assign custom breaks.

using the World Borders Dataset, download from: `http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip`

```
library(GISTools)
library(rgdal)

shape_file <- readOGR(dsn ="/home/hamid/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3", layer = "TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3")

    shades <-auto.shading(shape_file@data$POP2005, cutter = quantileCuts, n=5, cols = brewer.pal(5, "Blues"))
    choropleth(shape_file, shape_file@data$POP2005, shading =  shades)                      
    choro.legend(70.00000,32.50000, shades)
```

Can anyone help please?